# Color mapping of data on a date vs time plot

Tags: python, pandas, imshow

I am trying to plot 3 variables x,y,z on a 2d plot, with x (date) on the x axis, y (time) on the y axis and z (temperature) mapped with a colorscale. 
I have the three variables available within a pandas Dataframe and created an extra column with the datenumber so that matplotlib can work with it.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

data=pd.DataFrame() 
data['datenum']=mdates.date2num(data['Date'])
```

Example:

```
            Date Time     Tgrad   datenum
0     2016-08-01   00 -0.841203  736177.0
1     2016-08-01   01 -0.629176  736177.0
2     2016-08-01   02 -0.623608  736177.0
3     2016-08-01   03 -0.615145  736177.0
4     2016-08-01   04 -0.726949  736177.0
5     2016-08-01   05 -0.788864  736177.0
6     2016-08-01   06 -0.794655  736177.0
7     2016-08-01   07 -0.775724  736177.0
8     2016-08-01   08 -0.677951  736177.0
```

I have been trying to follow this suggestions:

[matplotlib 2D plot from x,y,z values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39727040/matplotlib-2d-plot-from-x-y-z-values)
[Dates in the xaxis for a matplotlib plot with imshow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23139595/dates-in-the-xaxis-for-a-matplotlib-plot-with-imshow)

But have not been successful due to the wrong shape of my input data I think. I have tried something like this:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.imshow(data['Tgrad'], extent = [min(data['datenum']), max(data['datenum']),min(data['Time']), max(data['Time'])], cmap="autumn", aspect = "auto")
ax.xaxis_date()
```

But get a ValueError:

```
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence
```

Is it necessary to have the data as numpy array or any other type? And how can I map the data once I have it in a different format?

Thanks you for helping.
Vroni

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`imshow` requires a 2d array as input. You'll need to reformat your data into a 2d array: `Date` x `Time` with `Tgrad` as your values. Pandas makes this fairly easy with `pivot`. It does require that you have nicely spaced data points, i.e., a grid-like data set (same `Time` values for each `Date`). The post you linked would be useful if data points were not neatly scattered in 2d space. Also, there's no need to convert to a numpy array as matplotlib can handle dataframes.

```
C = data.pivot(index='Time', columns='Date', values='Tgrad')

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.imshow(C)
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer. That works perfect and is so straight forward and easy. Perfect!