# Scatter plot density in python from data in csv

Tags: python, scatter-plot, data-analysis, density-plot

I have a very huge data set of 18000 players. Every player has a feature Overall and Finishing for example, and I want to make scatter density plot because with "normal" plot I can't where is more and where is less players.

Normal scatter plot code looks like this...

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

DATA_LOCATION = "main_players.csv"
FIRST_ATTRIBUTE = "Finishing"
SECOND_ATTRIBUTE = "Overall"

datas = pd.read_csv(DATA_LOCATION)
x = datas[[FIRST_ATTRIBUTE]]
y = datas[[SECOND_ATTRIBUTE]]
plt.scatter(x, y, color='r')
plt.xlabel('Finishing')
plt.ylabel('Overall')
plt.title('Odnos overall i finishinga')

plt.show()
```

I look on the Internet and I find a code to do the following:

```py
# libraries
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# create data
x = np.random.normal(size=50000)
y = x * 3 + np.random.normal(size=50000)

# Big bins
plt.hist2d(x, y, bins=(50, 50), cmap=plt.cm.jet)
#plt.show()

# Small bins
plt.hist2d(x, y, bins=(300, 300), cmap=plt.cm.jet)
#plt.show()

# If you do not set the same values for X and Y, the bins aren't square !
plt.hist2d(x, y, bins=(300, 30), cmap=plt.cm.jet)

#plt.show()
```

And I only replace them x with my x, and y also, but it doesn't work.

I expect the output (density plot) to look like this:

[image]

Comment: How does your scatterplot look now? Without the data, we cannot reproduce the current behaviour ad see how it differs from the expected result.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to plot a density map in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24119920/how-to-plot-a-density-map-in-python)

Comment: @alec_djinn This Not a duplicate of this question. OP needs a to plot a 2D histogram of (x, y) pairs. The question you mentioned is about plotting an (x, y, z) image with `imshow`.

Comment: OP, can you show your attempt at using the `hist2d` function?

Comment: @Keldorn the output suggested by the OP looks like the solution given by one of the answers. It was obtained using plt.pcolormesh

Answer (score 0):

Querying a dataframe with a list of column names, like in your code:

```
x = datas[[FIRST_ATTRIBUTE]]
y = datas[[SECOND_ATTRIBUTE]]
```

yields pd.Dataframes, which plt.hist2d cannot deal with

try:

```
x = datas[FIRST_ATTRIBUTE]
y = datas[SECOND_ATTRIBUTE]
```

to get pd.Series. These you should be able to plot with plt.hist2d