# How to get a 2D density plot with contourf

Tags: python, matplotlib, contourf

I want to get a 2D density plot by using "contourf plot" tool in Python, but the result shows two "white noise" regions.

[image]

The color of these regions should be the same with the color nearby, so I think this is because of the rendering problem. How to solve this problem?

There seems no errors in my database, because if I plot these same data on a 3D sphere, then the result shows in a normal way.

Front:

[image]

Back:

[image]

Here are my codes of 2D plot:

```
x = np.load('x.npy')   
y = np.load('y.npy')   
z = np.load('z.npy')

fig = plt.figure()
plt.figure(figsize=(6,2.75),dpi=200,frameon=True)
cm = plt.cm.get_cmap('jet')
plt.contourf(x,y,z,500,cmap=cm)
cbar = plt.colorbar()
tick_locator = ticker.MaxNLocator(nbins=3)
cbar.ax.tick_params(labelsize=20)
plt.xticks(fontsize=20)
plt.yticks(fontsize=20)
cbar.locator = tick_locator
cbar.update_ticks()
plt.tight_layout()
plt.gca().invert_yaxis() 
plt.show()
```

Here are my data:

```
x=[[0.         0.02108451 0.04216903 ... 3.09942362 3.12050814 3.14159265]
[0.         0.02108451 0.04216903 ... 3.09942362 3.12050814 3.14159265]
[0.         0.02108451 0.04216903 ... 3.09942362 3.12050814 3.14159265]
...
[0.         0.02108451 0.04216903 ... 3.09942362 3.12050814 3.14159265]
[0.         0.02108451 0.04216903 ... 3.09942362 3.12050814 3.14159265]
[0.         0.02108451 0.04216903 ... 3.09942362 3.12050814 3.14159265]]

y=[[-3.14159265 -3.14159265 -3.14159265 ... -3.14159265 -3.14159265
-3.14159265]
[-3.09942362 -3.09942362 -3.09942362 ... -3.09942362 -3.09942362
-3.09942362]
[-3.0572546  -3.0572546  -3.0572546  ... -3.0572546  -3.0572546
-3.0572546 ]
...
[ 3.0572546   3.0572546   3.0572546  ...  3.0572546   3.0572546
3.0572546 ]
[ 3.09942362  3.09942362  3.09942362 ...  3.09942362  3.09942362
3.09942362]
[ 3.14159265  3.14159265  3.14159265 ...  3.14159265  3.14159265
3.14159265]]


z=[[0.00085484 0.00069078 0.00055568 ... 0.00055568 0.00069078 0.00085484]
[0.00085484 0.00069092 0.0005559  ... 0.0005559  0.00069092 0.00085484]
[0.00085484 0.00069131 0.00055655 ... 0.00055655 0.00069131 0.00085484]
...
[0.00085484 0.00069131 0.00055655 ... 0.00055655 0.00069131 0.00085484]
[0.00085484 0.00069092 0.0005559  ... 0.0005559  0.00069092 0.00085484]
[0.00085484 0.00069078 0.00055568 ... 0.00055568 0.00069078 0.00085484]]
```

Comment: Could you share the code/data that you used to produce the image? My guess is that in those regions the data contains inf's and these just get rendered as white (i.e. they are treated as masked regions).

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and learn [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).
In order to get help, you will need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  If your question includes a Pandas DataFrame, please provide a [reproducible pandas example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answers. The data I checked that does not contains 'inf'. I added my codes. @Matt Pitkin

Comment: [How to plot 2D Density](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24119920/how-to-plot-a-density-map-in-python) reposted from a link-only [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76412655/7758804) by [RMC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/21725086/rmc)