# producing plots with colormaps in python

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, plotly

I have a three column data; I want to plot a scatterplot with the first two columns and colormap the data along the third axis. How can this be done using any of the plotting modules available with python ?

Comment: You mean a [contour plot like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9008576/8881141)?

Comment: Not exactly what I was looking for but this will be very helpful. I can play with this one. Thanks a lot !

Comment: I added some keywords to attract the right people. Maybe you want to add more details, how your desired graph differs from a heatmap or a contour plot.