# Smooth Contourf plot completely filled

Tags: python, matplotlib, contourf

I have the data with (X,Y,Z) values. I tried to make a density plot with Z values for intensity. However the plot I get is not smooth and and has polytope i.e not completely filled.

The following is the code with the [Data](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1HtRr21iUuYoAU-XKAWhjhFtP6EwA2Fdw/view?usp=sharing)

but I want to obtain smooth and completely filled plot

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import griddata
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import xlrd
location = "~/Desktop/Data.xlsx"
data = xlrd.open_workbook(location)
sheet = data.sheet_by_index(0)
sample=2000

x=np.array(sheet.col_values(0))[0:sample]
y=np.array(sheet.col_values(1))[0:sample]
z=np.hamming(9000)[0:sample]
print z
def plot_contour(x,y,z,resolution = 500,contour_method='cubic'):
    resolution = str(resolution)+'j'
    X,Y = np.mgrid[min(x):max(x):complex(resolution),   min(y):max(y):complex(resolution)]
    points = [[a,b] for a,b in zip(x,y)]
    Z = griddata(points, z, (X, Y), method=contour_method)
    return X,Y,Z

X,Y,Z = plot_contour(x,y,z,resolution = 500,contour_method='linear')

plt.style.context("seaborn-deep")

plt.contourf(X,Y,Z)
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

This is the output:

[image]

This is what I want to achieve using contourplotf:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`plt.contourf()` is not the main problem here, it's just working with the data it has. The problem is the linear interpolation in `scipy.interpolate.griddata()`.

I recommend not using `griddata`, but instead using one of the following methods:

- [**`scipy.interpolate.Rbf()`**](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.Rbf.html#scipy.interpolate.Rbf) — this is what you were using before ([see my previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58202164/3381305)).
- [**`verde`**](https://github.com/fatiando/verde) — an awesome gridding package.
- [**`sklearn.gaussian_process`**](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/gaussian_process.html) — or some other prediction model.

All of these methods will fill in the grid. If you plot the result with `plt.imshow()` you'll get the type of plot you show in your question — that is not a `plt.contourf()` plot.

[Here's a demo notebook](https://github.com/agile-geoscience/xlines/blob/master/notebooks/11_Gridding_map_data.ipynb) showing all of these approaches (including `griddata`).

Comment: yes, I was using scipy.interpolate.Rbf() but apparently the plot was pixalated (no matter the resolution. The problem is indeed the data is not enough so I was able to follow you advice and look into GP interpolation to produce more data. Got what I was looking for. Cheers for coming back.