# Interpolating irregularly located data to

Tags: java, interpolation, worldwind

I am trying to display a colored surface in [Worlwind Java](http://worldwind.arc.nasa.gov/java/), where the colors depend on latitude/longitude located values (e.g temperature) from a set of irregularly located data. I'm using the example found in the [gov.nasa.worldwindx.examples.analytics](http://builds.worldwind.arc.nasa.gov/worldwind-releases/1.3/docs/api/gov/nasa/worldwindx/examples/analytics/package-summary.html) package. There is a class Interpolator2D there but it doesn't seem to be able to compute irregularly located data.

As far as I know I'm missing only one thing in order to do that : a way to generate a grid of regularly placed points from a set of randomly located points. So far I don't have a way to do that.

Putting aside all the WWJ stuff, what I need is a way to generate a interpolated (and maybe extrapolated) grid of values from a set of arbitrary located values.

Any idea, code, API or algorithm is welcome. It doesn't matter if the solution is not working in lat/lon coordinates, arbitrary coordinates are fine.

PS : Basically what I want is to do this in java : https://stackoverflow.com/a/3867302/1435322

Thanks.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I'm trying to do the [exact same thing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24663580/linear-interpolation-of-scattered-2d-data) with no luck =(