# Finding nearest xy-point in numpy array and second nearest with condition

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, tree

My problem is like the problem in the thread [Finding index of nearest point in numpy arrays of x and y coordinates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10818546/finding-index-of-nearest-point-in-numpy-arrays-of-x-and-y-coordinates), but it's extended:

For better visualization here's an image
(manipulated image, original from: *by 112BKS - Eigenes WerkOriginal graph/Data from [.. ? ..], CC BY-SA 3.0*, [link to page](https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/index.php?curid=5949185)):
[image: source: Von 112BKS - Eigenes WerkOriginal graph/Data from [.. ? ..], CC BY-SA 3.0, https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/index.php?curid=5949185]

On the one hand there is a array `datafield`. It consists of a numpy array with elements `[value x y]`. That are the thin blue lines with the numbers (they are the `value`). On the other hand there is the array `orangeline` in a numpy array with elements `[x y]`.

What I want to do is to calculate the `value` of any elements in `orangeline`.
 I visualized one concrete element of `orangeline` with the green circle. The value for it can I interpolate with the two elements from `datafield`, visualized with the triangles. As result I get for the green circle a `value` between 225 and 230.

**First step:** 
Find for every element in `orangeline` the closest element in `datafield`.
(In the example that is the pink triangle.)

**Second step:**
 Find for every element in 'orangeline' the closest element in `datafield` but with another `value` than the one from the first step. 
(In the example that is the brown triangle.)

**Third step:** Interpolate the `value` for every element in `orangeline` from those the two founded values and the distances to those elements.

First step can be solved with

```
mytree = scipy.spatial.cKDTree(datafield[:, 1:3])
dist1, indexes1 = mytree.query(orangeline)
```

But now I don't know how to filter the datafield for the second step. Is there a solution?

Comment: Have you considered [using `griddata`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3867302/190597) to interpolate `datafield`'s values to `orangeline`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With help from [@unutbu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/190597/unutbu)'s comment I found this solution which works quite good also in those cases where the `orangeline` goes not through the field.

Here are the functions for the grid:

```
import matplotlib.mlab as mlab
import numpy as np
import scipy

def define_grid(rawdata):
    xmin, xmax = np.amin(rawdata[:, 1]), np.amax(rawdata[:,1])
    ymin, ymax = np.amin(rawdata[:, 2]), np.amax(rawdata[:,2])

    x, y, z = rawdata[:, 1], rawdata[:, 2], rawdata[:, 0]

    # Size of regular grid
    ny, nx = (ymax - ymin), (xmax - xmin)

    # Generate a regular grid to interpolate the data.
    xi = np.linspace(xmin, xmax, nx)
    yi = np.linspace(ymin, ymax, ny)
    xi, yi = np.meshgrid(xi, yi)

    # Interpolate using delaunay triangularization
    zi = mlab.griddata(x,y,z,xi,yi)
    return xi, yi, zi

def grid_as_array(xi,yi,zi):
    xi_flat, yi_flat, zi_flat = np.ravel(xi), np.ravel(yi), np.ravel(zi)

    # reduce arrays for faster calculation, take only every second element
    xi_red, yi_red, zi_red = xi_flat[1::2], yi_flat[1::2], zi_flat[1::2]

    # stack to array with elements [x y z], but there are z values that are 'nan'
    xyz_with_nan = np.hstack((xi_red[:, np.newaxis], yi_red[:, np.newaxis],
                              zi_red[:, np.newaxis]))

    # sort out those elements with 'nan'
    xyz = xyz_with_nan[~np.isnan(xyz_with_nan).any(axis=1)]
    return xyz
```

Another function to find the closest point from the grid for the values from orangeline:

```
def closest_node(points, datafield):
    mytree = scipy.spatial.cKDTree(datafield)
    dist, indexes = mytree.query(points)
    return indexes
```

And now the code:

```
# use function to create from the raw data an interpolated datafield
xi, yi, zi = define_grid(datafield)

# rearrange those values to bring them in the form of an array with [x y z]
xyz = grid_as_array(xi, yi, zi)    

# search closest values from grid for the points of the orangeline
# orangeline_xy is the array with elements [x y]
indexes = self.closest_node(orangeline_xy, xyz[:,0:2])

# take z values from the grid which we found before
orangeline_z = xyz[indexes, 2]

# add those z values to the points of the orangeline
orangeline_xyz = np.hstack((orangeline_xy,orangeline_z[:, np.newaxis]))
```