# Convert (latitude, longitude, variable) scattered dataset to gridded data

Tags: python, pandas, gridding

I have a pandas data frame (90720 rows) consisting of longitude, latitude, and variable columns. The data represent points on a 1.3 km resolution grid but are not in any particular order within the data frame. An example of the dataset looks like:

| lon | lat | var |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 40.601700 | -90.078857 | 0.006614 |
| 40.598942 | -90.031372 | 0.048215 |
| 40.592426 | -89.920563 | 0.012860 |
| 40.591480 | -89.904724 | 0.006642 |
| 40.590546 | -89.888916 | 0.005383 |
| 43.642635 | -89.904724 | 0.012860 |
| 40.590546 | -84.545715 | 0.012860 |

I would like to convert these lat/lon/var points into a gridded dataset. Most approaches I have tried (df.pivot) require significant memory due to the size of the data frame. The final gridded data should have a shape of (288,315). Ultimately, I want to plot this data with plt.colormesh() to compare it with other datasets. I appreciate any suggestions!

Comment: The way to bucket data for this would be to normalize your data to a value between [0,1] and then multiply that by your max grid size for that axis.  Since x_norm(x) = (x - x_min) / (x_max - x_min) you'll need to know the max and min values for each column then you should be able to handle each row one at a time by applying a norm function to lat and lon.  Keep in mind that The Earth is not a flat plane and simple normalization like this will get weird near the poles.  Consider [S2 Buckets](http://s2geometry.io/)

Comment: What should the output data look like, e.g. after this pivoting you did?

Comment: I can plot the data using geopandas. I would like to be able to work with as a gridded dataset, so I can compare it with other datasets (calculate means/std devs/etc) spatially. I am sure there are other work arounds, but this is where my brain can make sense of things I guess. 

I'd like the data output to be a 2-D array where the arr[x,y] value corresponds to the lat/lon location. The data is on a curvilinear grid, so calculating a lat/lon range and dividing it evenly doesn't quite work and degrades the resolution a bit. Are they any other options?

Comment: This is kind of what I was thinking, but I know there are likely more efficient approaches. 

lons = np.array(df['lon'].unique())
lats = np.array(df['lat'].unique())

df_2d = []
for i in lons:
    for j in lats:
        for ind in df.index:
            if (df['lon'][ind] == i) & (df['lat'][ind] == j):
                df_2d[i,j] = df['var'][ind]

Comment: I think the issue I still have with the suggested solutions is the assumption that x = np.linspace(xmin, xmax, nx). I'm working with an irregular grid, and this assumption gets wonky near the poles of my spatial domain.

Answer (score 1):

This is strongly inpsired by [Resampling irregularly spaced data to a regular grid in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3864899/12846804) from 12 years ago. I updated the code to work in current Python, and improved readability. It uses `plt.pcolormesh`. I suppose this is what you meant when requesting *plt.colormesh*.

With `df` the dataframe of your suggested input data:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.interpolate import griddata

# grid sizing
# number of grid points:
nx, ny = 288, 315
# grid window
xmin, xmax = 40, 45
ymin, ymax = -91, -84

# Generate a regular grid to interpolate the data.
X, Y = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(xmin, xmax, nx), 
                   np.linspace(ymin, ymax, ny))

# Interpolate using "cubic" method
Z = griddata(points = (df.lon, df.lat),
             values = df['var'],
             xi = (X, Y),
             method = 'cubic'))

# Plot the results
plt.figure()
plt.pcolormesh(X, Y, Z)
plt.scatter(x=df.lon, y=df.lat, c=df['var'])
plt.colorbar()
plt.axis([xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax])
plt.xlabel('longitude')
plt.ylabel('latitude')
plt.title('Overlay: Scatter and Grid')
plt.show()
```

With your initial dataset as circles:

[image: Gridded scatter, cubic interpolation]